# Logrotate Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, logrotate

Is logrotate set up by default on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS?

Or do I need to configure it? I can see /etc/cron.daily/logrotate so I guess it should be working out of the box?

Is it rotating all files inside /var/log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is installed.

Default configuration is in `/etc/logrotate.conf`.

Application-specific is kept in `/etc/logrotate.d`

You can check status what currently get rotated with command:

```
cat /var/lib/logrotate/status
```